# how to uninstall Flashbuilder manually.

Tags: windows-7, adobe, uninstallation, flash-builder

I've flashbuilder 4.6 and I need to uninstall it. It appears to be missing the installation package, and as such it doesn't appear in the control panel->uninstall list for windows 7.

I have filed a case with adobe for help (as its a paid product), but after month & 1/2 no answer.

So any suggestions on how to get rid of it including any links it will have to the registry or similar. It must be a clean uninstall as to install the newer version the current one must be removed and the newer version installation knows that I have it (previous version) installed already.

I have tried the uninstall tool called Revo as well without success.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to find the **exact** version of the software I used to install it originally. Then once I ran the installer, (for the already installed software) windows picked up the installation packager and I could uninstall it.

Once removed I could then install the newer version of the same software.